# AWS API Gateway PrivateLink and ApiKey authentication discussion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Let's say we have an API hosted on an EC2 Instance in a private NPC that requires APIKey Authentication.

Suppose we want to expose this API on AWS API Gateway with OAuth2.0 via Lambda Authorizer and then VPC Link to the actual private API. Would it be possible for the PrivateLink request to the NLB to add this ApiKey or how could this APIKey be added to the final request to the private EC2-hosted API?